# Problema al acceder a boton de elementor con js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, botón, elementor

Estoy intentando bloquear un botón de un formulario por pasos de elementor, el problema es que al intentar guardar el botón a bloquear en una variable esta variable es null, por alguna razón no quiere agarrar el elemento es como sino existiera

Javascript:

```
let zipInput = document.querySelector("[name='form_fields[zipcode]'");

let stepZip = document.querySelector(".elementor-field-group-zipcode_step .e-form__buttons__wrapper__button-next");

console.log(stepZip);
```

Html

```
<div class="elementor-field-type-step elementor-column elementor-field-group-zipcode_step elementor-col-100 e-form__step elementor-hidden">
  <div class="e-field-step elementor-hidden" data-label="" data-previousbutton="" data-nextbutton="" data-iconurl="" data-iconlibrary="fas fa-star" data-icon=""></div>

  <div class="elementor-field-type-html elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-field_1bcedc7 elementor-col-100">
    <h3><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">¿Cuál es su código postal?</font></font></h3>
    <img src="https://umanzorconstruction.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/icon-zip.png" style="display: block; margin: auto">
  </div>
  <div class="elementor-field-type-number elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-zipcode elementor-col-20 elementor-field-required">
    <label for="form-field-zipcode" class="elementor-field-label elementor-screen-only"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">¿Cuál es su código postal?</font></font></label>
    <input type="number" name="form_fields[zipcode]" id="form-field-zipcode" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Ingresa tu código postal" required="required" aria-required="true" min="" max="">
  </div>
  <div class="e-form__buttons elementor-column elementor-col-100"><div class="elementor-field-group e-form__buttons__wrapper elementor-field-type-previous"><button type="button" class="elementor-button elementor-size-sm e-form__buttons__wrapper__button e-form__buttons__wrapper__button-previous"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Atrás</font></font></button></div>
  <div class="elementor-field-group e-form__buttons__wrapper elementor-field-type-next">
    <button type="button" class="elementor-button elementor-size-sm e-form__buttons__wrapper__button e-form__buttons__wrapper__button-next"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Próximo</font></font></button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me parece que tu error esta aca:
"[name='form_fields[zipcode]'".
Prueba con "[name='form-fields[zipcode]'", guion al medio, no abajo.

Comment: No ese elemento si me lo reconoce, el problema es que no me agarra el boton, el codigo funcionaba bien un formulario normal pero al adapatarlo un formulario por pasos ya no me agarra el boton

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionarlo sin declarar la variable antes, solo llamando al boton cunado se activa la funcion

```
<script>
let zipInput = document.querySelector("[name='form_fields[zipcode]'");

const zipCodes = ["70510","70511","70420","70710","71401","70421","70711","71301","71302","71303","71306","71307","71309","71315","70031","70340","70422","71403","70426","70712","70032","71001","71218","70512","71002","71003","71404","70513","70704","70714","70514","71405","70036","71110","70515","71219","71220","71221","70715","70801","70802","70803","70804","70805","70806","70807","70808","70809","70810","70811","70812","70813","70814","70815","70816","70817","70818","70819","70820","70821","70825","70826","70827","70831","70835","70836","70837","70874","70879","70884","70892","70894","70895","70896","70898","71004","70630","70037","70093","70341","71406","71407","71006","71222","70342","71007","71008","71009","70427","70429","71223","70038","71320","71111","71112","71113","71171","71172","70343","70039","71409","70040","70516","70517","70718","70518","70719","71322","70041","70738","70431","70519","71225","71410","70631","71411","70520","70721","71016","70521","71323","70522","70043","70044","70523","71324","70524","71226","70344","71325","71227","70525","71414","71415","71326","70722","71416","71417","71229","71418","70723","71419","71018","71327","71019","70433","70434","70435","70632","70526","70527","71230","71021","70345","70725","70528","71232","71233","70706","70726","70727","70633","70634","70030","70047","71328","71422","70346","70352","71234","71023","70637","71423","71235","71024","70353","71329","70529","71330","70049","71331","70531","70638","71051","71424","70532","70050","71425","71237","70533","71238","70729","70534","70730","70535","70537","70639","71333","71240","71241","70640","71334","71426","71427","71428","71429","70436","70437","70732","71242","71430","71243","71459","70538","70438","70733","71027","70354","70540","70051","70734","71432","70355","71028","70356","71336","71029","71433","71030","70736","70357","71031","70707","70737","71245","70052","71032","70643","70541","70358","70644","70359","71435","70441","70739","71033","70053","70054","70056","70740","70542","70645","70057","71034","71339","70401","70402","70403","70404","71340","70058","70059","71037","70646","71038","71039","71341","70743","71438","71247","70744","71040","71439","71043","70360","70361","70363","70364","70442","71044","70443","70747","70543","70647","70748","71045","70749","70544","71342","70546","71249","71250","71251","71343","71440","70548","71046","71047","71441","70062","70063","70064","70065","70444","71253","70648","70750","71443","70068","70069","70372","70650","70445","70501","70502","70503","70504","70505","70506","70507","70508","70509","70593","70596","70598","70067","70549","70601","70602","70605","70606","70607","70609","70611","70612","70615","70616","70629","71254","70752","70373","70550","71345","70651","71346","71446","71496","71447","70551","70753","71348","71256","71048","70754","70755","70374","71049","71448","70652","70446","70552","70756","70070","70071","70569","70447","70554","70448","70470","70471","71259","71052","71350","71449","70757","71260","71351","70072","70073","71450","70375","70449","70555","71452","71353","71261","70075","70556","70653","70001","70002","70003","70004","70005","70006","70009","70010","70011","70033","70055","70060","70558","71055","71058","70654","71201","71202","71203","71207","71209","71210","71211","71212","70377","71354","71454","71060","71455","71355","70380","70381","70759","71356","70559","70076","70450","70390","70451","71456","71457","71458","71497","71460","70560","70562","70563","71461","70121","70123","70141","70181","70183","70112","70113","70114","70115","70116","70117","70118","70119","70122","70124","70125","70126","70127","70128","70129","70130","70131","70139","70142","70143","70145","70146","70148","70150","70152","70153","70157","70158","70160","70161","70163","70165","70170","70172","70174","70175","70177","70178","70179","70182","70184","70185","70186","70187","70189","70190","70760","70078","71357","71462","70079","70761","71263","71264","71463","70655","71061","71465","70570","70571","70762","71466","70391","71358","70080","70392","70763","70452","71063","70575","70339","70081","70453","70576","71360","71361","71266","70656","71064","70764","70765","70393","71362","71065","70082","71467","70454","70767","70577","70083","71066","70769","70770","71067","71468","71268","70394","70657","70578","71269","70580","70658","70084","71363","71068","70581","71469","70455","71069","70772","70456","70659","70773","71270","71272","71273","70774","70457","70085","70775","70776","70086","71366","71367","70582","70087","71070","71071","70395","70583","71072","71101","71102","71103","71104","71105","71106","71107","71108","71109","71115","71118","71119","71120","71129","71130","71133","71134","71135","71136","71137","71138","71148","71149","71150","71151","71161","71162","71163","71164","71165","71166","71073","71368","71472","71473","71369","71474","71275","70660","71475","70777","70458","70459","70460","70461","70469","71276","70778","71277","70462","71075","70661","71279","71280","71078","70662","70663","70664","70665","71079","70463","70584","70780","71281","71282","71284","70465","71080","70397","70301","70302","70310","70466","71477","71286","71371","71479","70782","70585","70792","71480","70090","70467","70091","70783","71373","70586","70668","70092","71082","70784","70785","70589","71375","70786","70591","71291","71292","71294","70669","70094","70096","70787","70788","70789","71483","71295","71378","71485","70592","70791","71486"];


  zipInput.oninput = function() {
    
    if(zipInput.value.length == 5){
        for(let i=0; i <= zipCodes.length; i++){
            
            if(zipInput.value == zipCodes[i]){
                document.querySelector('.elementor-field-group-zipcode_step .e-form__buttons__wrapper__button-next').disabled = false;
                break;
            }else{
                document.querySelector('.elementor-field-group-zipcode_step .e-form__buttons__wrapper__button-next').disabled = true;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
  }

// console.log(array.length);
</script>
```